# how to multiply two rows mysql php

Tags: php

This code show simple result how to multiply two rows

Example  30 days multiply by 400 salary.
So how can I do this please help me to fix this issue.

```
 <?php
    while ($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
    {

     //get data
    $workerid = $runrows['workerid'];
    $keywords = $runrows['workername'];
    $salary = $runrows['salary'];
    $days = $runrows['days'];

    echo "<table  class='hovertable' width='100%'>";

    echo "<tr width='50%' onmouseover=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#999999';\" onmouseout=\"this.style.backgroundColor='#d4e3e5';\"><td width='20%'><a href=\"workerdetail.php?id=$id\" class=\"style1\">$workerid</a></td>
    <td width='20%'>$workername</td>
    <td width='20%'>$salary</td>
    <td width='20%'>$days</td>

    echo "</table>";
    }

    }
    }

?>
```

Comment: something like this:

`$monthSalary = $salary * $days `

Comment: What does this have to do with MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

```
 $salary = $runrows['salary'];
```

Do what you want with the code above, multiply, deduct, add... to it. Is a basic maths, see the `=` sign? just place `$salary = $days * $runrows['salary'];`

Comment: how to multiply salary row to days row??

Comment: Check it again. It is as simple as doing a simple maths. @user1833487

Comment: not working dear its show error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_ECHO in /home/.php on line 301

Comment: @user1833487 what is in line 301? copy and paste it here. You have forgotten a `"` or `'`

Comment: $days = $runrows['days'];
 301 line it is

Comment: @user1833487 the `unexpected T_ECHO error`occures, if there is something wrong with the way you are using `echo` it could be, maybe the syntax before and after it is not write. post you code in pastebin.com and I will help you out

Comment: ok i solve the error but now echo only salary not multiplying

Comment: Maybe the day is one, so it is multiplying it by one, otherwise if you use the code as I gave you, it should work 100%.

Comment: i got answer $Total=$runrows['days']*$runrows['salary']; now its working